# Where is the original of the statement "the most derived class's ctor needs to directly call the virtual base class's ctor"?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

While I learn how to implement a final class in C++, I find such a statement:

["the most derived class's ctor needs to directly call the virtual base class's ctor."](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.11)

However, I can't find the original of the statement in the C++ standard. (N3126)

Who can tell me the exact page number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++03, it's § 12.6.2 5

> Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class as described below, virtual base classes shall be initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base class names in the derived class base-specifier-list.
>
> ...

In the current draft for C++0x (N3126), it's § 12.6.2 10, which is page 270:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-ﬁrst left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-speciﬁer-list
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

N3126 is ***not*** the C++ standard.

It's a draft for the upcoming C++ standard.

But anyway, the info about initialization is in the section about initialization for derived classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. Could you give me the exact page number and the original text?